# Which IP address should I useconnecting to rasperrypi?

Tags: connection, static-ip, setup

While connecting to RasberryPi via ssh I was trying to connect and I had a couple of issues:

1. Sometimes when I use 'hostname -I' to get the IP address I could see 2 IP addresses? Could you explain me why?
2. I tried to connect via Ethernet but I could not see the RasberryPi from my PC, I tried via ssh command and also via Ping but it seemed as if the device didn't exist. What could it be?
3. Finally, I managed to 'send ping' using broadcast ip address, is this the IP i should use for establishing the connection with pi? When I am using broadcast address to connect via

ssh pi@broadcastIP

I am getting an error:

ssh: connect to host *ipaddress* port 22: Network is unreachable

I am a total beginner in PI and I am basically trying to play with the TurtleBot3 and I got stucked at connecting my pi (p. 3.2.3)

https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/sbc_setup/#sbc-setup

Comment: what are the two IP addresses? one for ethernet one for wifi maybe? try `ip a` to see which ip address is for which network interface

Comment: There are 3 distinct questions here.  It's usually best to ask one question per post, so that the answers can be properly targeted.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

I'm certain the problem is that you use a static ip address. Most questions on this site are about static ip addresses. No, it does not make things simple. On the contrary, it makes things more complicated if you do not understand detailed networking. Please have a look at all the other answers about [static ip address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=static+ip+address).

Answering your points:

1. *Sometimes when I use 'hostname -I' to get the IP address I could see 2 IP addresses? Could you explain me why?*
   As long as we don't now what ip addresses exactly are shown, I can only guess. It could be that your interface has two ip addresses, or there are shown the addresses of all interfaces if you have more than one interface.
2. *I tried to connect via Ethernet but I could not see the RasberryPi from my PC, I tried via ssh command and also via Ping but it seemed as if the device didn't exist. What could it be?*
   I'm sure its a problem with the static ip address.
3. *Finally, I managed to 'send ping' using broadcast ip address, is this the IP i should use for establishing the connection with pi?*
   To ping the broadcast address will ping all devices on the network at the same time. The replies of all devices at the same time will result in very high load of the network traffic. Therefore pinging the broadcast address is a very bad practice and should not be used, in particular on enterprise networks. The network manager will complain and suspect an intrusion attack.

I suggest you start with a fresh flashed [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/). With a wired ethernet connection this is working out of the box without any modifications. Then you should be able to ping the RasPi from the PC with

```
pc ~$ ping raspberrypi.local
```

If this doesn't work, then the problem is the PC and fix it. The management console must support **mDNS**. On a MS Window$ 10 PC it is supported with installing **Bonjour**. On a Linux box it is supported with the **avahi** daemon which is mostly available by default.

If you can ping the RasPi then you can enable **ssh** on it and connect with:

```
pc ~$ ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

Comment: i tried to ping to the raspberrypi but i got an error message ping: unknown host raspberrypi.local

Comment: @MaciekWoźniak I have updated the answer with a hint about using **mDNS**.

Comment: I'm curious: What led you to the conclusion that the OP is using a static IP?

Comment: @Seamus It's flagged.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from your PC instead:

```
$ ssh pi@XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
```

Instead of `XXX.XX.XXX.XXX`, use one of the IP addresses you got from `hostname -I`. You might try one, and then the other.

Why 2 addresses?

The answer can be found by entering `man hostname`... refer to the `-I` option. Learn to use the system manuals - there is (usually) one for every command.

#### EDIT; Addendum:

It's been brought to my attention that you have applied the `static-ip` tag to your question. However, I found nothing in the [turtlebot reference](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/sbc_setup/#sbc-setup) you provided to suggest that was done as part of the turtlebot installation. Also, your description of the problem suggests that you are able to connect to your RPi... somehow - perhaps over WiFi??

Your question, as currently worded, omits important details; e.g. what are those two IP addresses? The "turtlebot" software installation adds another layer of uncertainty. I could go on, but that seems pointless without some feedback & clarification from you.

I will say this: If you want to communicate with your RPi from your PC over the Ethernet connection (without *routing*), it is necessary that your PC and the Ethernet adapter in your RPi are on the same [**subnet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is usually to ignore the IP Address

Connect with [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)

`ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`

Comment: hi, thanks, I tried it via ethernet and connecting pi to the same wifi as my pc but i got the same error : ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: Name or service not known